# 1 правка требует проверки, но при переходе пишет, что "очередь кончилась"

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок

Сверху, рядом с надписью "очередь проверок" висит единичка, в подсказке к ней пишет, что "1 предполагаемая правка требует утверждения". При нажатии на единичку пишет, что очередь проверок кончилась. При переходе на общую страницу проверок не показывает проверок для правок.

Я подозреваю, что это висит предложенная мной же правка описания метки GDI, хотя, возможно, я ошибаюсь.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Ага, это именно ваша правка. Число на кнопочке считается для всех без учета индивидуальных исключений. Такая экономия ресурсов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а где же тогда «72 голоса за закрытие»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не знаю как у других, у меня после выхода из беты в это число входят только предлагаемые правки. Пока была бета, там считались все проверки.

Comment: @insolor, у меня в данный момент на красной плашке в верхней чёрной строке (там, где у вас на картинке цифра «1») стоит цифра «79», что примерно соответствует сумме проверок во всех очередях, если открыть http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review в анонимной сессии. // у меня лишь одно разумное предположение, что, в противоречие словам NickVolynkinа, цифра на плашке всё-таки зависит от репутации (10000 баллов, т.е., очередной для вас порог репутации, у меня, насколько помню, уже было при выходе из беты).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я в общем-то так и думал.